# Cannot run Hello World C++ program

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am just starting C++ and downloaded a compiler and an IDE, both eclipse, and tried to make my first C++ program. I use the Hello World C++ Makefile Project, and add the all the stuff on the next page. I then build the program, and the build says this:

> 12:30:00 **** Build of configuration Default for project HelloWorld! **** make all  Cannot run program "make": Launching failed
>   Error: Program "make" not found in PATH PATH=[C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin/client;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_91/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program
>   Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\Jen\Desktop\eclipse;] 12:30:00 Build
>   Finished (took 122ms)***

I run the program, and it says:

***Launch failed. Binary not found.***

This is the code for the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("Hello World!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There are two errors, too:

1. Function "puts" couldn't be resolved.
2. Symbol "EXIT_SUCCESS" couldn't be resolved.

Thanks in advance!

Nate N.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I followed the advise of user4581301 and the code now says this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hi World" << endl; // prints Hi World
    return 0;
}
```

The build looks like this:

13:22:26 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project HiWorld ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\HiWorld.o" "..\src\HiWorld.cpp" 
g++ -o HiWorld.exe "src\HiWorld.o"

13:22:27 Build Finished (took 835ms)

But now the program, although it does run, doesn't print anything.

Thanks in advance,

Nate N.

Answer (score 0):

> Launch failed. Binary not found.

well this is shown because you have 2 errors.
any error means = no binary compiled/linked
no binary compiled/linked = cant launch something which doesnt exist

solution = fixing the errors

```
#include #include
```

^ also this is not valid

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot run program "make": Launching failed Error: Program "make" not found in PATH

Kaboom! No make, no build, no binary to run.

Some compilers don't ship with Make out of the box, but I don't see any signs of a compiler toolchain in your path at all.

Eclipse is an IDE with support for a wide variety of different compilers. as a result it does not ship with one. Since the error message shows you are building on Windows, your simplest option is [one of the many MinGW variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW). And Since you are just starting, I recommend starting off with the plain-vanilla MinGW as Eclipse requires next to no extra configuration to use it.

Just make sure you follow the instructions to install msys along with MinGW to get `make`.